# help with tables

Tags: tables

[image]

Does anyone know why my board is cut?

```
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}
Primer entero &
  Segundo entero &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Valor suma \\ según calculadora\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Valor resta \\ según calculadora\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Valor producto \\ según calculadora\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Valor cociente \\ según calculadora\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Valor resto \\ según calculadora\end{tabular} \\
0 & 2 & 2  & -2 & 0  & 0   & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 2  & 2  & 0  & -   & - \\
4 & 4 & 8  & 0  & 16 & 1   & 0 \\
4 & 6 & 10 & -2 & 24 & 0.6 &   \\
2 & 9 & 11 & -7 & 18 & 0.2 &  
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have 7 fairly wide column headers, and you only specify (fairly wide) line breaks on five of them.  The table is too wide, so it runs off the page.  What would you like to happen instead?

Comment: Compress the table more so that it comes out all in one

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution with the help of the `geometry` package (to help have more sensible margins) and the `\thead` command, from `makecell`:

```
     \documentclass{article}

     \usepackage{makecell}
    \title{tabletest}\author{Ego}
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

    \begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
    \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
    \thead{Primer\\ entero} &
      \thead{Segundo\\ entero} &
      \thead[lc]{Valor suma \\ según\\ calculadora} &
      \thead[lc]{Valor resta \\ según\\ calculadora} &
      \thead[lc]{Valor producto \\ según\\ calculadora} &
      \thead[lc]{Valor cociente \\ según\\ calculadora} &
      \thead[lc]{Valor resto \\ según\\ calculadora} \\
    0 & 2 & 2 & $ -2 $ & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    2 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & $ - $ & $ - $ \\
    4 & 4 & 8 & 0 & 16 & 1 & 0 \\
    4 & 6 & 10 & $ -2 $ & 24 & 0.6 & \\
    2 & 9 & 11 & $ -7 $ & 18 & 0.2 &
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the package tabularray and the package changepage

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}% for the test
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{changepage}%<-- to change page width locally
\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt
\lipsum{1}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}%<-- change the margin
  \begin{tblr}{
      hlines,vlines,
      colspec = {*{7}{X[m,c]}},%
      row{1}={font=\bfseries}
    }
    Primer entero & Segundo entero & Valor suma según calculadora & Valor resta según calculadora & Valor producto  según calculadora & Valor cociente según calculadora & Valor resto según calculadora \\
    0 & 2 & 2  & -2 & 0  & 0   & 0 \\
    2 & 0 & 2  & 2  & 0  & -   & - \\
    4 & 4 & 8  & 0  & 16 & 1   & 0 \\
    4 & 6 & 10 & -2 & 24 & 0.6 &   \\
    2 & 9 & 11 & -7 & 18 & 0.2 &
  \end{tblr}
\end{adjustwidth}
\lipsum{2}
\end{document}
```

[image]